# Подсчитать количество латинских букв в текстовом файле

Tags: java, файлы, текст

есть задание подсчитать количество латинских букв в текстовом файле, у меня получилось только переводить в верхний регистр буквы.

```
static void copyToUpperCase(String fileNameFrom, String fileNameTo) {
    try {
        FileReader e = new FileReader(fileNameFrom);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(e);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameTo));

        String s;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            out.write(s.toUpperCase() + "\n");
        }

        out.close();
        e.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception var6) {
        var6.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    copyToUpperCase("E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\file.txt", "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\mahesh.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `getBytes()` класса `String`, он преобразует буквы в байты, используя кодировку по умолчанию.

Далее, по таблице кодировки определите в каком диапазоне байт расположены латинские буквы и пройдитесь циклом по файлу. В цикле последовательно считывайте байты из файла и сопоставляйте их с диапазоном латинских символов

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно обойтись и без явного преобразования в байты, а определять принадлежность каждого элемента строки к промежутку a - z и A - Z.

(Таблица ASCII содержит латинские буквы от a до z продряд, и буквы A - Z также подряд)

Чтобы проверить принадлежность буквы к промежутку надо проверить, что:

```
(('a' <= x && x <= 'z') || ('A' <= x && x <= 'Z'))
```

где x - символ из файла

Если данное условие истинно, то символ принадлежит {a,b,c,...,x,y,z,A,B,C,...,X,Y,Z}; если условие ложно - то нет.

Читать содержимое файла лучше посимвольно.

(например как описано в данном вопросе):
[Считывание из файлов посимвольно в массив JAVA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161174/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-java)